# BeforeAll and AfterAll in javascript test cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I want do something before all tests, then after?  What is the best way to organize my code? For example: backup some variables -> clear them -> test something -> restore backups. 'beforeEach' and 'afterEach'  are too expencive. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

A pretty simple solution:

```
describe("all o' my tests", function() {

  it("setup for all tests", function() {
    setItUp();
  });

  describe("actual test suite", function() {

  });

  it("tear down for all tests", function() {
    cleanItUp();
  });

});
```

This has the advantage that you can really put your setup/teardown anywhere (eg. at the begining/end of a nested suite).

Comment: You may introduce a code-smell if you mutate a state in an `it` block. The `it` blocks are solely for logic-less asserts.

Answer (score 7):

Jasmine >=2.1 supports `beforeAll`/`afterAll` for doing one-time setups and teardowns for your suite.

If you are using Jasmine 1.x you could use an `it` for that (as suggested by others) or load a node_module that supports beforeAll/afterAll, for example [jasmine-before-all](https://github.com/testdouble/jasmine-before-all).

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function before all tests start is trivial; however, Jasmine (1.3.1, at least) doesn't allow you to specify your own finished callback outside of the reporter API.

Here's a quick little hack I found on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jasmine-js/1LvuiUPunwU/SXPo6PMGSSMJ). Add this to your `SpecRunner.html` or equivalent.

```
var oldCallback = jasmineEnv.currentRunner().finishCallback;

jasmineEnv.currentRunner().finishCallback = function () {
    oldCallback.apply(this, arguments);

    // Do your code here
};

jasmineEnv.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine provides options to write your own reporter and attach it. To implement a reporter, there are basic callbacks like `initialize`, `jasmineStarted` and `jasmineDone`. With this you can achieve your requirement. For example, in Jasmine 2.0, refer to `jasmine-html.js` file to have a basic understanding.

Comment: Check the Jasmine2.0 standalone release, the location of the file is "jasmine-standalone-2.0.0\lib\jasmine-2.0.0\jasmine-html.js".